# Javascript: Best practice for clean and optimised way of writing Functions and Conditional checks

Tags: javascript, function

I am was looking into javaScript best practices for clean and optimised code, and I'm not sure about what is the best approach for my situation. I edited my code for clarity and it contains dummy code.

1. Writing Nested Functions

I want to do something after the page has loaded, so I have written some code that executes after page load. So I have defined all the functions inside this load function. It's working perfectly.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var conditionOne = true;
  if(conditionOne) {
    firstFunction();
  }

  function firstFunction() {
    console.log('running first function');
    secondFunction();
  }

  function secondFunction() {
    console.log('running second function');
  }

  //

  //

  //

  function tenthFunction() {
    console.log('running tenth function');
  }

});
```

Alternative way would be like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var conditionOne = true;
  if(conditionOne) {
    firstFunction();
  }
  
});

function firstFunction() {
  console.log('running first function');
  secondFunction();
}

function secondFunction() {
  console.log('running second function');
}

//

//

//

function tenthFunction() {
  console.log('running tenth function');
}
```

This surely is more cleaner as the functions are separated and they are only invoked in the after load listener event. Does this also have any performance optimisation. I believe the second one is the most optimised in this scenario. Please correct me if there are any other better ways.

2. Conditional check before executing function.

Suppose that I need to have conditional check before executing the function, I thought of 2 ways of doing it.

First

```
function mainFunction() {
  if(conditionOne) {
    firstFunction();
  }
  secondFunction();
  if(conditionThree) {
    thirdFunction();
  }
}

function firstFunction() {
  console.log('running first function');
}

function secondFunction() {
  console.log('running second function');
}

function thirdFunction() {
  console.log('running first function');
}
```

Second

```
function mainFunction() {
  firstFunction();
  secondFunction();
  thirdFunction();
}

function firstFunction() {
  if(conditionOne) {
    console.log('running first function');
  }
}

function secondFunction() {
  console.log('running second function');
}

function thirdFunction() {
  if(conditionThree) {
    console.log('running first function');
  }
}
```

Second one looks like clean code, but I am not sure if its costly, Can anyone suggest which would be a better and optimised way.

Comment: If you want to stop polluting the global namespace, then you're left with alternative 1 only. It's basicly a good way, but the same can be achieved with JavaScript modules, code blocks,  an anonymous IIFE, or in some cases using `DOMContentLoaded` event rather than `load` event.

Comment: "*Does this also have any performance optimisation.*" - barely. Putting functions in the global scope is a bit more messy and a tiny bit slower, but it absolutely doesn't matter for code that runs only once on the `load` event anyway. "*Second one looks like clean code, but I am not sure if its costly*" - no, the cost is about the same. What matters for clean code is what these functions actually do, what (descriptive) names they have or not, and whether the conditions would need to be repeated if the function would be called also from somewhere else.

Comment: Your question may be a better fit on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ because "best practice" and "clean" are a matter of opinion — there is no straightforward answer, which is what Stackoverflow wants.

Comment: When creating functions withing a load callback, every time load callback is invoked functions will be created. By defining them outside load they will be created once and reference to it will be saved for further calls (this is really micro-optimization, but it is good practice). I would suggest you never have these conditions in function. Go for (Conditional check before executing function. - First) way